# form data json/ajax script doesn't work on new server (windows to linux)

Tags: php, ajax, json

I'm moving a site from a Windows server to a Linux server running PHP 5.2.15.

There is a large application form on the site, that uses javascript, jquery, and ajax to validate/add fields, and json to encode/decode the input data, and PHP to send the email.

This form works fine on the Windows account. When I move it to our Linux server, everything works except the email that is sent is empty. There is a PHP error that gets printed and sent with the email:
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/account/public_html/application/application_email.tpl on line 4

the first few lines of that file look like:

```
<?php 

 $infoArr = get_object_vars( $info );
 foreach( $infoArr as $key=>$val ) {
    $parts = explode( "_", $key );
    $number = array_pop( $parts );
    if( count( $parts ) >= 1 && is_numeric( $number ) )
    {
```

So to me, the error says that $info is empty. The php variable $info is created in another file called submitApp.php. The first few lines of that file are:

```
<?php
 require_once( "emogrifier.php" );

 $info = json_decode( $_REQUEST['data'] );

 ob_start();
 require( "application_email.tpl" );
 $css = file_get_contents("application_email.css");
 $html = ob_get_contents();
 ob_end_clean();
```

So, something is not happening with the json_decode function. Using Live HTTP headers in Firefox, I can see the form input data being passed (via POST) to submitApp.php. So, I know the data is getting there. Here is the line from LiveHTTPheaders:

```
POST /~account/application/submitApp.php data=%7B%22name%22%3A%22Test+Name%22%2C%22address%22%3A%22111+Test+Street%22%2C%22city%22%3A%22Testville%22%2C%22state%22%3A%22NJ%22%2C%22zip%22%3A%2212121%22%2C%22email%22%3A%22test%40test.com%22%2C%22
```

and so on.

So it appears as though json_decode isn't working, and therefore isn't putting the contents of `$_REQUEST['data']` into the variable `$info`.

Any ideas? I'm not new to php, but I am new to json, ajax, and this "emogrifier" thing.

Thank you!

Comment: I should clarify that the form isn't blank...the email still shows the markup from application_email.tpl. It's just that none of the form data makes it into the template before the email is sent.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem. My JSON working fine in local server which is window server while I transformed to Linux I got same problem, After I tried post menthod for getting data it working fine. I had replaced `json_decode($_REQUEST['json']` to `json_decode($_POST['json']` Finally found it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so if you think that $info is empty, you should be testing for that condition so you can handle it gracefully.  The following may seem elementary, but I like to eliminate the simplest solutions first to make sure that we are doing things the hard way.  Therefore I like to check my variables before I use them because I get tired of NULL reference errors.

```
if( isset($info) )
{
  //... do something
}
else
{
  //... gracefully handle the error
}
```

As for the suspicion of the json code not working, you should test the $_REQUEST['DATA'] variable first:

```
if( isset($_REQUEST['data]) )
{
  // DEBUG -- attempt to view the data:
  print_r($_REQUEST['data']);

  // ... perform json extraction
}
else
{
  // ... handle the error gracefully
}
```

Usually when you use a HTML Form element that data is sent via a POST request.  I know that GET/POST requests also end up in the REQUEST super global array, but you might want to verify that your data is not in the POST array...

Let us know your results :)

Comment: Genius! I used the POST request, and added stripslashes...and it works! I tried using POST prior, but without stripslashes.